# PHP variable used to generate code in a while command

Tags: php, sql, charts, google-visualization

I've been building Google Charts and having lots of 'fun' getting my SQL commands to fit how Google wants it, but, I'm finally done with that and now need to move on to the more complex parts. Variable number of elements.

My charts are based on how many stores a user has, I've been using a dummy set-up based off of having three stores to date, but a user can have *n* stores and need to adjust my google charts to fit this variable input.

So far I've done pretty well, I'm using queries to pull the number of stores a user has which in turn substitutes into the SQL query so we return the right number of rows in the dataset for Google Charts and I can substitute the store names into the header, it's just the PHP I'd found googling that writes the SQL outputs into the Google chart expected format I'm struggling with.

```php
function drawChart1() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', 'Store A', 'Store B', 'Store C'],
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT
                DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month',
            CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS 'Store A',
            SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Store A_Base',
            CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS 'Store B',
            SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Store B_Base',
            CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS 'Store C',
            SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Store C_Base'
        FROM data 
                WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
                GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
                ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";

        $Sat = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
            echo "['".$row['Month']."',".$row['Store A'].",".$row['Store B'].",".$row['Store C']."],";
        }
    ?> 
]);
```

So, that all works, gives me my three dummy stores of 1, 2, 3 (Store A, Store B & Store C) and makes a pretty little chart.
And so I adjusted it to the following:

```php
    <?php
    //dynamically build chart queries
    $sql_prep = "SELECT d.store_list AS NUMB, s.name AS NAME FROM data d INNER JOIN store_list s ON d.store_list=s.store_id WHERE d.status != '' AND d.store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ") GROUP BY store_list";
    $sql_code = $conn->query($sql_prep);
        while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $select = $select . "CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  '" . $row['NAME'] . "',SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '" . $row['NAME'] . "_Base',";
        $cstores = $cstores . "'" . $row['NAME'] . "', " ;
        $carray = $carray . ",\".\$row['" . $row['NAME'] . "'].\"";
        }
    ?>
...
function drawChart1() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', <?php echo $cstores ?>],
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT
            " . $select . "
            DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month'
        FROM data 
        WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
        GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
        ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";

        $Sat = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
             echo "['".$row['Month']."'".$carray."],";
        }
    ?> 

]);
```

And it's almost there, $select works, I then replaced $cstores and it still worked, but I'm stuck on $carray. If I echo it out, it's perfectly built the string needed to go in there, creating `,".$row['Store A'].",".$row['Store B'].",".$row['Store C']."` but that doesn't work so obviously isn't supported by PHP (which I don't really know, I just keep poking it in different ways till it works)

So I'm now stuck. I need to write out the *n* columns of stores into the array that builds the Google Chart but my very poor understanding of PHP is in my way. Is there a better way of writing echo `"['".$row['Month']."',".$row['Store A'].",".$row['Store B'].",".$row['Store C']."],";` if you you don't know the column headers of Store A, Store B etc..?

Comment: try to pass all the data to `JavaScript` and draw chart using it

Comment: Would you be better off building an array of the data and just using `json_encode()` at the end?

Comment: I don't know JavaScript so I'll go give json_encode() a google, might be the quickest win for me cheers!

Comment: Hmm, I've been giving it some searching, but, I think even if the data's encoded as json I need to specify the headers so not sure how this helps me get around my issue.

Similarly all the javascript examples I've been looking at have hardcoded headers = \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, bit of a workaround but updated the SQL and changed the outputting to Google Chart:

```
<?php
//dynamically build chart queries
$sql_prep = "SELECT d.store_list AS NUMB, s.name AS NAME FROM data d INNER JOIN store_list s ON d.store_list=s.store_id WHERE d.status != '' AND d.store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ") GROUP BY store_list";
$sql_code = $conn->query($sql_prep);
$select = '';
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $select .= ", CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  '" . $row['NAME'] . "' ";
        $cstores = $cstores . "'" . $row['NAME'] . "', " ;

    }
?>

<!--https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

  function drawChart1() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Month', <?php echo $cstores ?>],
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT
            QUOTE(DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y')) AS 'Month'
            ". $select ."
        FROM data 
        WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
        GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
        ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";

    $Sat = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    foreach( $Sat as $key => $array ) {
        echo("[");
        foreach( $array as $attribute => $value ) {
            echo $value. ",";
        }
        echo("],");
    }
?>
```